# swift - primaryActionTriggered - sender problem

Tags: swift, uitextfield, ibaction

I have a tableview with reusable cells, and each have a textfield (like quantity field at the basket). And I need to update some data every time when editing did end or user tap somewhere outside keyboard, so I use both

```
    @IBAction func quantityEditingDidEnd(_ sender: UITextField) {
            //code
    }
    @IBAction func quantityPrimaryActionTriggered(_ sender: UITextField) {
            let cell = sender.superview?.superview as! BasketTableItemCell
            let indexPath = tableView?.indexPath(for: cell)
            //code
    }
```

And I have an error with `primaryActionTriggered`, because sender should be `Any`, but I need to use `UITextfield` to detect which cell is clicked. How can I solve this - use `primaryActionTriggered` and detect sender as `UIView` at the same time?

*** UPD
I've tried change my code this way -

```
@IBAction func quantityPrimaryActionTriggered(_ sender: Any) {
print("test")
        if let textField = sender as? UITextField {
            let cell = textField.superview?.superview as! BasketTableItemCell
            let indexPath = tableView?.indexPath(for: cell)
            //code
        }
}
```

but notice, that there wasn't line `"test"` at the console. So I guess, that this `@IBAction` doesn't work at all. Maybe the point is in the reusable cell? `didEndEditing` works well. Connection to StoryBoard is ok too.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the element as type Any and cast it after like this

```
@IBAction func quantityPrimaryActionTriggered(_ sender: Any) {
        if let textField = sender as? UITextField {
            let cell = textField.superview?.superview as! BasketTableItemCell
            let indexPath = tableView?.indexPath(for: cell)
            //code
        }
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry! Didn't see that! What textField's action you linked to quantityPrimaryActionTriggered ?

Comment: added xcode's screenshot. both primaryAction and editingDidEnd.

Comment: Well maybe you can use another action to do what you wants, it depends what you are waiting from textfield to trigger the function; maybe you want to call editingDidBegin.
You can also use delegate function in your code, maybe it can help